# How can I get more control on URL in magnolia blossom?

Tags: magnolia

I am able to create an template in blossom.
Using this template I am able to create the page from magnolia author admin panel.
Is there any way I can create a page in blossom it self so that I can have more control on the urls.

Can anyone having idea please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

With Blossom you couple the page template with a spring controller.
You can choose any page name (and URL) you like, but every time you see a page based on a specific template, the controller tied with that template is called.

Comment: Daniele,I do having the same issue.where can I provide the URL for a page.When I click create page.I have an option to add  name, description and the template

Comment: by default the page name define the path for that page, if for example you add a page called 'hello' at root level the url of the page will be <your context path>/hello. However if you need to do forwards or redirects you can follow the instructions here: https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/URI+mapping#URImapping-Configuration